# Select & hightlight my own draws on OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to add a select interaction for hightlighting the features I drawed like in this example but on my own draws:

http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/select-features.html

To Hightlight the features I use ol.events.condition.pointerMove

```
var highlighter = new ol.interaction.Select({
     layers: [featureOverlay],
     condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});
```

In my example, when I draw a polygon, start the "Hightlighter" and go on the drawed feature it seems like the selection toggle switch.

I think this code worked on the 3.13.1 version

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jfjucnj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your drawn features to an ***unmanaged*** layer (the old `ol.FeatureOverlay`) with `featureOverlay.setMap(map);`. I'm not sure why you need this and why this flickering but if you change to a ***managed*** `ol.layer.Vector` then this behavior is gone:

```
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: featureStyle
});
map.addLayer(featureOverlay);

var drawPolygon = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: featureOverlay.getSource(),
  type: 'Polygon'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/p1q7s50k/

Comment: Thank you Jonatas, your code works well. 
Adding the vector layers is not what I prefer because now I see them on the layersTree of my app and they aren't always on top, but I think I can modify it and avoid this behavior

Comment: @A.Bahi So you could post your solution and mark it as correct and finish this topic.